# i3 on Debian 9 Stretch -- installation error -- "unmet dependencies"

Tags: debian, i3

While trying to install i3 (window manager) on my Debian machine I had some wired dependency error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: gnome-settings-daemon (< 3.19.92) but 3.14.2-3+deb8u1 is to be installed
                            Breaks: mutter (< 3.19.92) but 3.14.4-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Last Saturday -- while running `apt-get upgrade` -- Debian upgraded from 8 "Jessie" to 9 "Stretch". Could the problem be connected to that upgrade?

Researching for aid I couldn't find something which fits to my situation. While I enjoy Debian much, I'm not a power user. I would be very thankful for any support.

`apt-cache policy gnome-settings-daemon mutter` shows

```
gnome-settings-daemon:
  Installed: 3.14.2-3+deb8u1
  Candidate: 3.22.2-2
  Version table:
     3.22.2-2 0
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.14.2-3+deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ oldstable/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mutter:
  Installed: 3.14.4-1~deb8u1
  Candidate: 3.22.3-2
  Version table:
     3.22.3-2 0
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.14.4-1~deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ oldstable/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-settings-daemon mutter`?

Comment: @StephenKitt : Thank you :) Here you find the requested output
https://pastebin.com/Sjcr4Lxu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve got a mixture of sources causing conflicts, in particular codename-based repositories (“jessie”) along with generic repositories (“stable”).

Now that you’ve (partially) upgraded to Debian 9, you need to edit your sources so that

- all lines referring to “oldstable” are commented out
- all lines referring to “stable” refer to “stretch” instead
- all lines referring to “jessie” refer to “stretch“ instead

By specifying the release codename, you’ll avoid the sudden upgrade when the next release comes out.